# Signals - kill the process with CTRL-C and stop the process with CTRL-Z + measure the time

Tags: c, linux, c++11, signals, sigint

I need to make a program where the process indefinitely writes three dots. When pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (using *SIGINT*) the program needs to write the goodbye message and kill the process. When pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then *fg* (using *SIGCONT*) the program need to measure the time which passed during this time in seconds and for every second that has passed the program needs to write one dot. When the program write all dots of one, it returns to three dots.

```
$ ./program
...
...
...
...
... <pressing Ctrl+Z>
$ <we wait few seconds (5)>
$ fg
.
.
.
.
.
...
...
...
...
<pressing Ctrl+C>
Ending
$
```

I managed to get through the first part (killing the process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while in an infinite loop) but I can't find the way to measure the time after stopping the process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then continue with fg.

Current working code:

```
bool stop = true;

void end(int sig){
    printf("ending\n");
    //signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    //kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
    stop = false;
}

int main(){
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = end;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);
    while(stop) {
        printf("...\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How I'm planing to measure the time:

```
t = clock();
pause();
t = clock() - t;
double time = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("time: %f", time);
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Added. And thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `man signal`,

> `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught or ignored.

The only solution I see is to poll current time, and measure the delta between current and previous sample. A difference large enough would most likely indicate that the program has been stopped.

This is not precise, but I guess that for your exercise can be good enough.

PS: don't `printf` in a signal handler.

Comment: Yeah but where do I star the time measure? I'm trying to measure the time with time.h libraries. But I don't know where to put it.